# Find function couple with loop gives 1004 error

Tags: excel, vba, loops, variables, find

Im currently working on a code that gets a employee number and replace it with their name in the same cell. It works with a loop that go and look for a match in an hiden sheets.

Problem is for some reason i always get a 1004 error from my Find fonction which i coudnt resolve with all of google for some reason : here's my code:

```
Sub Employe()
Dim ash As Worksheet
Set ash = ActiveSheet
        Dim i As Integer
        k = 4
        no = 0
        nom = ""
        nos = ""
            For i = 1 To 4 'Goes trough the 4 employee nb input
            ash.Select
            k = k + 1
            no = Cells(k, 3).Value 'Gets the employee number value 

                If no <> "" Then 'look if loop cell is empty
                nos = CStr(no)
                Sheets("Liste Employé").Select 'select the hidden sheets (not hidden as of right now we'll get to that other problem later)

                Dim foundRng As Range
                Set foundRng = Range("A2:A91").Find(nos) 'Go look for the matching number in reference sheets range

                If foundRng Is Nothing Then
                   MsgBox ("Entrer un numéro d'employé valide")

                   Else
                   nom = CStr(foundRng)
                   ash.Select
                   Cells(k, 3).Value = foundRng 'give the value in original sheet

                End If

            End If

        Next
End Sub
```

The problem is link to this line :

```
Set foundRng = Range("A2:A91").Find(nos)
```

Which returns an 1004 error.

I think it has to do with the value of "foundRng" not resetting each loop but no clue how to fix it.

Thx yall, love

Comment: You can't select a hidden sheet...

Comment: Its not hidden as of right now, still not working

Comment: Looks like you're just replacing the number with itself though?

Comment: Well in the hidden sheet the number is paired with the name so the employee can put only the number, and get the exact speling of their name (i need the exact speling for futur data treatement)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to select a sheet before using Find (so you can safely hide it with no problem)

```
Set foundRng = Sheets("Liste Employé").Range("A2:A91").Find(what:=nos, lookAt:=xlWhole)
```

VLookup might be easier:

```
Sub Employe()
    Dim ash As Worksheet, rngInfo As range, res, c As Range
    Set ash = ActiveSheet
    Dim i As Long
    k = 4
          
    Set rngInfo = Sheets("Liste Employé").Range("A2:A91")

    For each c in Range("A4:A8").Cells
        If c.Value <> "" Then
            'lookup the name from ColB
            res = application.vlookup(CStr(c.Value), rngInfo, 2, False)
            If Not IsError(res) Then
                c.Value = res
            Else
                MsgBox "Entrer un numéro d'employé valide"
            End If
        End If        

     

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Had the first code working with some minor changes, but will try vlookup if its more efficient or convinient, im having another problem related to that code but i need to wait 90 min to repost (your really helpful thanks a lot)

Comment: Im new to the website so i dont know of to close this request, neither can i upvote your answers, il post my new issues after lunch break and try to find a way to close this one, thanks!

Comment: Typically a question with an accepted answer is considered "closed"